# CloudFormation condition lazy evaluation

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation

Is it possible to avoid evaluating a CloudFormation condition based on another condition? For example...

I have an AWS CloudFormation template with a parameter `EventSourceArn`:

```
Parameters:
  EventSourceArn:
    Type: String
    Default: ""
```

...and, using this parameter, I want to define conditions for the creation of certain resources:

```
Conditions:
  IsSqs: !Equals
    - !Select [2, !Split [':', !Ref EventSourceArn]]
    - "sqs"
  IsDynamo: !Equals
    - !Select [2, !Split [':', !Ref EventSourceArn]]
    - "dynamodb"

  # snip

Resources:
  EventSourceMappingForSqs:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::EventSourceMapping
    Condition: IsSqs
    # snip

  EventSourceMappingForDynamo:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::EventSourceMapping
    Condition: IsDynamo
    # snip
```

If `EventSourceArn` is not passed in and its value ends up as the default empty string, this template produces a stack error: `Template error: Fn::Select  cannot select nonexistent value at index 2`.  That is expected according to [the `Fn::Select` docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-select.html)...but, is there any way to avoid running the `!Select` completely, and just have `IsSqs` and `IsDynamo` correctly evaluate to false?

I've tried adding an extra condition before `!Select`, but it runs anyway:

```
# DOES NOT WORK:
Conditions:
  HasEventSource: !Not [!Equals [!Ref EventSourceArn, "" ]]
  IsSqs: !And [Condition: HasEventSource, !Equals [!Select [2, !Split [':', !Ref EventSourceArn]], "sqs"]]
```

What does work is defaulting the `EventSourceArn` value to `":::"`, but that seems ugly to me and I'd like to avoid it if there is a less-ugly way.

Comment: I don't think it's going to be possible. Conditions are pretty limited. You might be able to do a transform that changes the condition based on the data.

Comment: How about a default value for the parameter so `!Select` never fails?